# Location history shows wrong place

Tags: google-location-history

I am trying to find out how on Feb 18th and 19th of 2014, I was in Louisville Ky, but my location history is showing that I was in Somerset Ky.

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Your location was probably pulled from wifi only, as opposed to GPS (this saves battery; you can check this setting in settings > Location > mode).  The wifi setting pulls its location information from the ISP, rather than your actual physical location.  Mine frequently tags me a dozens of miles away.